# How to parse following json so that it is compatible with Realm?

Tags: android, json, realm

I am using Retrofit and RxJava with Gson to parse the json response. I have following json.

```
{
"data": [
{
"name": "Featured Albums",
"slug": "featured-albums",
"items": [
 {
"type": "album",
"title": "Ajambari",
"slug": "ajambariUPC027829302603",
"count": 10,
"duration": "",
"is_explicit": false,
"is_premium": false,
"is_trending": false,
"is_popular": false,
"is_featured": false,
"released_date": "",
"logo": ""
}
],
"total_items": 4,
"per_page_items": 6,
"prev_page_url": null,
"next_page_url": null,
"total_page": 1
},
{
"name": "Featured Movies",
"slug": "featured-movies",
"items": [
{
"id": 41,
"title": "Karamat",
"slug": "NPA0D1802638",
"logo": "",
"background": 
"",
"playlist": false,
"count": 1,
"redirect_link": "",
"created_date": 2013
}
],
"total_items": 9,
"per_page_items": 6,
"prev_page_url": null,
"next_page_url": "",
"total_page": 2
}
]
}
```

As you can see that "items" can have different structure. For this I used JsonArray for parsing items as:

```
public class HomeDatum extends RealmObject {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("slug")
@Expose
private String slug;
@SerializedName("items")
@Expose
private JsonArray items = null;
@SerializedName("total_items")
@Expose
private Integer totalItems;
@SerializedName("per_page_items")
@Expose
private Integer perPageItems;
@SerializedName("prev_page_url")
@Expose
private String prevPageUrl;
@SerializedName("next_page_url")
@Expose
private String nextPageUrl;
@SerializedName("total_page")
@Expose
private Integer totalPage;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}

public JsonArray getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(JsonArray items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public Integer getTotalItems() {
    return totalItems;
}

public void setTotalItems(Integer totalItems) {
    this.totalItems = totalItems;
}

public Integer getPerPageItems() {
    return perPageItems;
}

public void setPerPageItems(Integer perPageItems) {
    this.perPageItems = perPageItems;
}

public String getPrevPageUrl() {
    return prevPageUrl;
}

public void setPrevPageUrl(String prevPageUrl) {
    this.prevPageUrl = prevPageUrl;
}

public String getNextPageUrl() {
    return nextPageUrl;
}

public void setNextPageUrl(String nextPageUrl) {
    this.nextPageUrl = nextPageUrl;
}

public Integer getTotalPage() {
    return totalPage;
}

public void setTotalPage(Integer totalPage) {
    this.totalPage = totalPage;
}
```

But I am getting error: *Field "items" of type "com.google.gson.JsonArray" is not supported.* This is thrown by Realm. If I don't use Realm then it's working just fine.
So my question is how can I parse the above json so that it can be supported by realm.
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

you must use ResponseClass like below

```
public class ResponseClass {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private ArrayList<HomeDatum> items;

public ResponseClass(){};


public ArrayList<HomeDatum> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<HomeDatum> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

}

and pass it to Retrofit and  get the response with this code

```
ResponseClass response = response.body();
ArrayList<HomeDatum> items = response.getItems();
```

Comment: I have done that for "data", My question is for "items" key.